# Chrome app manifests ignored

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, lubuntu

Creating website shortcuts in Chrome through ⋮ > More tools > Create shortcut... creates an extension, with a manifest at `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/xxx...xxx/###...###/manifest.json`:

```
{
   "app": {
      ...
      "launch": {
         "web_url": "https://www.google.com/"
      }
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Editing the `"app"."launch"."web_url"` key does not change the target. Is the 'true' manifest stored somewhere else? Is it cached somewhere? How can I edit the URL target (other than by creating a new shortcut)?

Comment: Just to explain the reasoning behind the question, I'd like to link to a redirect URL, so I can't use the UI to create a shortcut - it won't be to the URL I want but to its redirect target.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/q/1588128/152004