# Where does Chrome store the URLs for web apps (desktop shortcuts that open in a new window)?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, path, shortcuts, web-application

I am using Windows 10 (21H2) and I have a semi-old chrome shortcut for a site, that I set up to open in a new window (so that it works like an app - create shortcut -> open in new window). Problem is, it doesn't work anymore - at least not since a chrome update a while ago. Instead of fussing around to figure out why it doesn't work, I just want to create the shortcut again, to not overcomplicate things. I have backups going back several years, so this shouldn't be hard to figure out. *Shouldn't.*

Problem is, I can't figure out where chrome stores the URLs for these shortcuts/web apps. The shortcut is a shortcut to `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=XXX`, the XXX being what looks like some kind of GUID.

To understand how this all works, I've created another "web app" to see how things change. I've already seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1588128/set-custom-url-for-chrome-chromium-desktop-app) but Chrome doesn't seem to be creating an extension with a matching string, as suggested in the answer. I've looked all around Google, and I can't seem to find anything there. I've analyzed the web app creation process with Process Monitor, and while I've found where it places Icons in the file system and uninstall information in the registry, I still have no clue where it stores the URL.

So where *does* Chrome store these URLs?

Answer (score 0):

An answer is found in the post
[Location of Chrome Web Apps (PWAs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470471/location-of-chrome-web-apps-pwas) :

> Windows 10/8/7: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\`
>
> macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Web Applications`
>
> Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web Applications`
>
> Linux (Chromium): `~/.config/chromium/Default/Web Applications`
>
> Chrome OS: `/home/chronos/Web Applications`

Note : I have found a shortcut that I created in the folders,
so the above might have changed with the latest Chrome versions :

- `C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications`
- `C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\Manifest Resources`

Comment: Unfortunately, that folder only seems to have an icon as well as an md5 hash for the icon file. There is no trace of a URL there.

Comment: I created a web-app shortcut and searched for its app-id. I added the folders I found to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that other folder also only seems to have icons. At least in my case there are three folders: `Icons`, `Icons Maskable` and `Icons Monochrome`. Icons has icons, the other two folders have nothing, and there are no files in the Manifest Resources (to avoid confusion: hidden icons are shown).