# In Chrome where are the urls for webapps (fullscreen shortcuts) stored?

Tags: google-chrome

I've found the following 2 pages relating to this subject, however neither really solved the problem for me:

[Where does Chrome store the URLs for web apps (desktop shortcuts that open in a new window)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1762340/where-does-chrome-store-the-urls-for-web-apps-desktop-shortcuts-that-open-in-a)

[Set custom URL for Chrome / Chromium Desktop App](https://superuser.com/questions/1588128/set-custom-url-for-chrome-chromium-desktop-app)

The second topic had some more useful information in it, and the following solution did technically work, but it leaves a really ugly pixelated icon down in the taskbar which cannot be changed

> I had the exact same problem. What worked for me was creating the Chrome (Brave) App using the same process and going to the Shortcut's profile. Can be found in (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Brave Apps) In that shortcut, I go to properties and in the target, instead of --app-id="". I change it to --app="". And now it will open my custom URL in the new window like an app (with no address bar and no toolbar).

The answer talking about how the webpage gets saved as an extension seemed like a better solution, but it simply didnt work for me, there is no extension folder with the same id as the webapp i created, so im at a dead end here.

I'm trying to create a webapp for instagram messages so i can answer messages on my pc and go directly to the messages page without being distracted by the main app, but for some reason when i navigate to the messages page and create an app from there it creates the app to simply instagram.com, the very first time the app opens once you create it, it lands on the correct messages page, however every subsequent time after that it will always simply open to the main instagram.com page, which is not what i want, or how i thought webapp creation worked on chrome?

Some of the other comments are talking about how it will create the app from the page youre on but that just doesnt seem the case with instagram for some reason.

If i take the app id from the shorcut it creates and type it into the 'everything' app to search my entire PC all it shows up is a couple folders that contain nothing but icons. I just want to find the file containing the specific url and edit it to the insta direct messages page so i can have it working functionally without seeing a horrible pixelated icon down in the task bar.

Anyone else had a similar problem? Any tips/advice would be great.